# On the $K$-topology on the real line

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $K = \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. If we call $\mathscr{B}$ the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ and the sets of the form $(a,b) - K$, then this generates a topology $\mathscr{T}_K$ called the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

We want to prove that standard topology on real line is strictly smaller than $K$-topology.

#### Attempt:

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the standard topology on line. We show $\mathscr{T} \subsetneq \mathscr{T}_K$

The inclusion is trivial as $\mathscr{T}_K$ contains all opens sets of standard topology. We still need to find some open set in $\mathscr{T}_K$ that is not open in standard topology.

Im trying to understand the k-open sets: Well, if $(a,b)$ does not contain $0$, then this would just be the standard open set. However, if $0 \in (a,b)$, then

$$ (a,b) - K = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a<x<b \; \; and \; \; x \neq 1/n \}$$

Now we may write this as $(a,0) \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} \left( \dfrac{1}{i+1}, \dfrac{1}{i} \right) \cup (1/N, b)$

Is this how we can write open sets?

Consider $(0,1)-K = \{0 \} \bigcup (1/[i+1], 1/i)$

So, this is not open in standard topology since $\{ 0 \}$ is not open. Is this correct?

Comment: $0\notin(0,1)$, so $0\notin(0,1)\setminus K$. Try $\Bbb R\setminus K$ instead.

Comment: Is my interpretation of k-open sets correct? Im having some difficulties visualizing them profesor

Comment: Just take any ordinary open set and throw out any points of the form $\frac1n$ that it happens to contain; that will still be open in the K-topology. Note that you **don’t** throw out $0$: your description of $(a,b)\setminus K$ should start with $(a,0]$, not $(a,0)$.

Comment: I see profesor: $ ( \mathbb{R} - K )^c = \bigcup_n \{ 1/n \} $ and this cannot be open in usual topology. This is true sir ?

Comment: $\Bbb R\setminus K$ is open in the K-topology by definition, and it’s not open in the usual topology, because $K$ is not closed in the usual topology: $0$ is in $\operatorname{cl}K$ in the usual topology.

Comment: Prof. Scott: can also argue as follows: since there is no open interval $(a,b)$ that contains $0$ and is contained $R - K$, then it is not open in the usual topology. right sir ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: thank sir! can you kindly help us here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703461/a-bf-subbasis-mathcals-for-a-topology-on-x-is-a-collection-of-subset thank sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $K$-topology is the topology where we add to the closed sets of the Euclidean real line a new closed set $K$ (new as it is not Euclidean closed as $0$ is a limit point of $K$, that is not in $K$). So in particular $K^\complement = \Bbb R \setminus K$ is not Euclidian open but *is* open in the $K$-topology, showing the proper inclusion.

It's of course not a coincidence that $0 \notin K$ and this new closed set $K$ will precisely be the counterexample to regularity....